# Cant get Nivo slider to work

Tags: html, css, nivo-slider

I want to integrate a nivo slider on this page [Link](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/) The slides should go into the screen I have on top on the page. At the moment I struggle to get the slider images into the screen image.

HTML:

```
<div class="top" >
<img src="screen.png" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px; " /> 
        <div class="slider">
            <img src="slide-1.png" alt=""  />
            <img src="slide-2.png" alt=""  />
            <img src="slide-3.png" alt=""  />
    </div>              
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content { height: 800px; width: 1000px; float: left; display: block; margin-top: 20px; }
#content .top { width: 1000px; height: 300px; display: block; float: left; position: relative; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 20px; }
#content .text3 { width: 200px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 20px; }
#content .text4 { width: 300px; height: 90px;margin-bottom: 10px; }
#content .face { width: 300px; height: 300px; display: block; float: left; position: relative; margin-top: 20px; }
#content .bottom { width: 1000px; height: 400px; display: block; float: left; position: relative; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 45px; }
#content .box1 { width: 236px; height: 350px; background:url(box1.png) no-repeat; display: block; float: left; position: relative; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 20px; }
#content .box2 { width: 236px; height: 350px; background:url(box2.png) no-repeat; display: block; float: left; position: relative; margin-left: 17px; margin-top: 20px; }
#content .box3 { width: 236px; height: 350px; background:url(box3.png) no-repeat; display: block; float: left; position: relative; margin-left: 17px; margin-top: 20px; }
#content .box4 { width: 236px; height: 350px; background:url(box4.png) no-repeat; display: block; float: left; position: relative; margin-left: 17px; margin-top: 20px; }
#content .slider { width: 360px; height: 235px; margin-left: 60px; margin-top: 40px; overflow: hidden; }
```

Here is my whole code:

HTML: [Link](http://pastebin.com/r1uAHKtK)

CSS: [Link](http://pastebin.com/66fVyDab)

What should be done to get the nivo slider running properly?

I used the Javascript and CSS from this site [Link](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/)

Comment: Where is the JS reference?

Comment: I posted the link of the Javascript I used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing `#slider` in the header but the div is a `class="slider`" change it to the ID or switch the id to the proper class

/**** EDITED ****/

Change your CSS to this:

```
#content .slider {
width: 350px;
height: 235px;
margin-left: 60px;
margin-top: 40px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 12px;
right: 133px;
}
```

Comment: Now I changed it to a class, but I cant get the slider into the screen on the image.

Comment: No, it was your positioning

Comment: Thank you very much. Would be nice if you upvote my question.

Answer (score 1):

you are calling nivo slider by id in js and while you are only using css class there in html
use this

```
$(window).load(function() {
                $('.slider').nivoSlider({
                        effect: 'random', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
                        animSpeed: 500, // Slide transition speed
                        pauseTime: 6000, // How long each slide will show
                        startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
                        controlNav: true, // 1,2,3... navigation
                        directionNav: false, // Next & Prev navigation
                        pauseOnHover: true // Stop animation while hovering
                });
        });
```

or wrapp a div named slider around slider class

Comment: Now I changed it to a class, but I cant get the slider into the screen on the image.

Comment: I need to position the slider on top of screen Image. How can it be done?

Comment: by position absolute see the css down there

Comment: Thank you very much. Would be nice if you upvote my question.